# Can piece go there? Chess function struggle in Python

Tags: python, class, object

I have a tuple of the size of the chess board, with objects containing their coordinates and if True (white) or False (black)

Board : tuple[int, list[Piece]]

I am trying to write a function to check if the piece can move or not, in this case if the cell is not occupied, or of if it is occupied check if it is the same side. If there are both of the same side let's say True, and True it cannot move there, if the side it is different it will be able to move there.

So far I have worked out that I can compare the self with the pieces in the tuple, and the only way to do this seems via a for loop. The problem is that it contains booleans and it compares to each one and returns what exactly ?

You can see that my code output is correct, when the 2 are same it will say you can't go there and viceversa. But I need to return a Bool.

Can someone help to implement this?

```
class Rook(Piece):
    def __init__(self, pos_X : int, pos_Y : int, side_ : bool):
        '''sets initial values by calling the constructor of Piece'''
        super().__init__(pos_X, pos_Y, side_)


    def can_reach(self, pos_X : int, pos_Y : int, B: Board) -> bool:
        '''
        checks if this rook can move to coordinates pos_X, pos_Y
        on board B according to rule [vertical and Horizontal move] and 
        [Rule4] A piece of side X (Black or White) cannot move to a location occupied by a piece of side X.] (see section Intro)
        Hint: use is_piece_at
        '''
      
        is_occupied = is_piece_at(pos_X, pos_Y, Board)
        if is_occupied == False:
          return True  #if it is not occupied you can always go there.
        if is_occupied == True:
          for piece in B[1]:
            print ("piece",piece.side_)
            print ("self",self.side_)
            if piece.side_== self.side_:
              print ("you can't go there")
              yes=
            elif piece.side_!= self.side_:
              print ("yes you can go there")
```

```
R0.can_reach(1,1, Board)

piece True
self True
you can't go there
piece False
self True
yes you can go there
piece False
self True
yes you can go there
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return False if any of the possible options in the for loop is False, you can set a parameter to True by default and switch it to False if it encounters a False move.

Does this fix your problem?:

```
class Rook(Piece):
    def __init__(self, pos_X : int, pos_Y : int, side_ : bool):
        '''sets initial values by calling the constructor of Piece'''
        super().__init__(pos_X, pos_Y, side_)


    def can_reach(self, pos_X : int, pos_Y : int, B: Board) -> bool:
        '''
        checks if this rook can move to coordinates pos_X, pos_Y
        on board B according to rule [vertical and Horizontal move] and 
        [Rule4] A piece of side X (Black or White) cannot move to a location occupied by a piece of side X.] (see section Intro)
        Hint: use is_piece_at
        '''
        reachable = True
        is_occupied = is_piece_at(pos_X, pos_Y, Board)
        if is_occupied == False:
          return reachable  #if it is not occupied you can always go there.
        else:
          for piece in B[1]:
            if piece.side_== self.side_:
              print ("you can't go there")
              reachable = False
          return reachable
```

Comment: It does not work,  it will always return false if I have 2 false and one true, in the loop. I am not sure why it does this. The problem is comparing booleans in a loop. I don't know if there is another way to implement this...
for example I use the following
R0=Rook(1,1,True)
R1=Rook(2,2,False)
R2=Rook(3,3,False)

Comment: Please specify the input and expected outcome in your question so we (I) can answer it correctly.